# Rationale behind generalized Pearson X^2 statistic in GLMs

Tags: generalized-linear-model, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

In GLMs the following goodness-of-fit statistic, which [McCullagh & Nelder (1982)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412317605) call the generalised Pearson $X^2$ statistic, is commonly used
$$
X^2=\sum (y - \hat\mu)^2 / V(\hat\mu) .
$$
My question is why not just use the "true" Pearson $X^2$ statistic, that is
$$
X^2=\sum (y - \hat\mu)^2 / \hat\mu
$$
instead of inventing a new one?

In other words, what is the advantage of the generalised version of the statistic over the traditional one?

Comment: Note that your "true" statistic only applies under a particular set of circumstances. This is a considerably more general situation.

Answer (score 0):

As Glen_b mentioned, the "true" statistic as you call it only makes sense when the variance of the distribution equals the mean, i.e. $V(\hat{\mu}) = \hat{\mu}$. And when do you see this? The Poisson distribution. This is the distribution that you'll usually run into when dealing with count data, especially count data in 2-way contingency tables.